# Return to the same view when no image is selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, json.net, entity-framework-5, c#-5.0

I have an upload control. But if the user didnt select an image and the press on the upload button, the user will get an message that he/she has to go back and try again, like this:

```
if (isSavedSuccessfully)
            {
                return Redirect(Url.Action("Edit", "Account") + "#tabs-2");
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Message = "Error in saving file, Go back and  try again" });
            }
```

but ofcourse this is not what you want. Because the message is in a seperate view, not in the view it self, where you can upload the image. But how to show the message in the same view, where you upload the image?

THis is my full method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditPhotos(UserProfile user, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {            
            bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;
            try
            {

                if (file != null || file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    if (IsImage(file) == false)
                    {
                        // Invalid file type
                        return Json(new { Message = "Error in saving file, Go back and  try again" });
                    }
                    int iFileSize = file.ContentLength;
                    if (iFileSize > 3048576)  // 1MB
                    {
                        // File exceeds the file maximum size
                        return Json(new { Message = "Image is to large , Go back and  try again" });
                    }                   
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var job = new ImageJob(file, "~/Images/profile/<guid>", new Instructions("mode=max;format=jpg;width=400;height=400;"));
                    job.CreateParentDirectory = true;
                    job.AddFileExtension = true;
                    job.Build();

                    var DirSeparator = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(job.FinalPath);

                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        string username = User.Identity.Name;                        
                        user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));
                        user.Image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                        file.InputStream.Read(user.Image, 0, file.ContentLength);
                    }
                    // Update fields                
                    user.ImageMimeType = file.ContentType;
                    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isSavedSuccessfully = false;

            }

            if (isSavedSuccessfully)
            {
                return Redirect(Url.Action("Edit", "Account") + "#tabs-2");
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Message = "Error in saving file, Go back and  try again" });
            }

        }
```

and this is my view for upload image:

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.UserProfile
@using ContosoUniversity.Source
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<div id="tabs-2">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditPhotos", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form_Id", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Profile Photo</h4>
            <hr />

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

            <div id="upload-choices">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-row">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            Upload an profile image not bigger then 3 MB
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    @if (Model.Image == null)
                    {
                        <th><img class="pull-left" src="~/Images/RockOnBycicle.png" width="200" height="150" alt="RockCycle" /></th>

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <th><img width="200" height="150" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Account", new { id =  Model.Id })"></th>

                    }
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="file" name="file" class="filestyle" data-icon="false">
            <br />
            <div class="progress progress-striped">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">0%</div>
            </div>

            <div id="status"></div>
            <br />          
            <div class="pull-left">
                <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" class="btn btn-default pull-left" />

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    }

    <br /><br /><br />
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.form.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-filestyle.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.form.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `ModelState` error and return the view (otherwise redirect), for example

```
if (isSavedSuccessfully)
{
    return Redirect(Url.Action("Edit", "Account") + "#tabs-2");
}
else
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Image", "your message");
    return View(user);
}
```